# How to merge two or more consecutive ‘styled-content’ element and convert into single while attribute have same?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

There are multiple ‘styled-content’ with different attributes @style and @style-type values and here we are try to merge only consecutive ‘styled-content’ element which attributes values are matching. Below is example case:

**NOTE:** The element 'styled-content' can have other element like as 'italic' & 'bold'. these element also should be retained. Moreover 'styled-content' element could be different parent element other than 'p'.

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<p content-type="new">For these purposes, the degree of relationship is determined as of the date of execution because of divorce. See <styled-content style="case" style-type="Case-Cal"><italic>Estate of Lira</italic></styled-content><styled-content style="case" style-type="Case-Cal"> (2012) 212 CA4th 1368</styled-content>.</p>
<p content-type="new">Under the <styled-content style="act" style-type="Act-Cal">Trust Law</styled-content>, you owe a duty (see <styled-content style="stat" style-type="Stat-Cal">Probate Code </styled-content><styled-content style="stat" style-type="Stat-Cal">&#x00a7;16061.5</styled-content>). We will discuss with you what specific actions you and we will take to fulfill these duties.</p>
<p content-type="new">Assets may be valued for federal estate tax purposes as of the alternate valuation date <styled-content style="case" style-type="Case-Federal"><italic>Estate of Edward H. Eddy</italic></styled-content><styled-content style="case" style-type="Case-Federal"> (2000) 115 TC </styled-content><styled-content style="case" style-type="Case-Federal">135</styled-content>. The IRS may grant an extension to make the election within the 1-year period even after a timely estate tax return has been filed.</p>
<p content-type="new">Prop Treas Reg see <styled-content style="pub" style-type="Ref-external-CEB"><italic>IRS Issues Temporary and Proposed Basis Consistency and Reporting Regulations,</italic></styled-content><styled-content style="pub" style-type="Ref-external-CEB"> 37 CEB Est Plan Rep 140 (Apr. 2016)</styled-content>.</p>
</root>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<p content-type="new">For these purposes, the degree of relationship is determined as of the date of execution because of divorce. See <styled-content style="case" style-type="Case-Cal"><italic>Estate of Lira</italic> (2012) 212 CA4th 1368</styled-content>.</p>
<p content-type="new">Under the <styled-content style="act" style-type="Act-Cal">Trust Law</styled-content>, you owe a duty (see <styled-content style="stat" style-type="Stat-Cal">Probate Code &#x00a7;16061.5</styled-content>). We will discuss with you what specific actions you and we will take to fulfill these duties.</p>
<p content-type="new">Assets may be valued for federal estate tax purposes as of the alternate valuation date <styled-content style="case" style-type="Case-Federal"><italic>Estate of Edward H. Eddy</italic> (2000) 115 TC 135</styled-content>. The IRS may grant an extension to make the election within the 1-year period even after a timely estate tax return has been filed.</p>
<p content-type="new">Prop Treas Reg see <styled-content style="pub" style-type="Ref-external-CEB"><italic>IRS Issues Temporary and Proposed Basis Consistency and Reporting Regulations,</italic> 37 CEB Est Plan Rep 140 (Apr. 2016)</styled-content>.</p>
</root>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="styled-content[@style[.='case'] and @style-type[.='Case-Cal']]">
    <styled-content>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[1][self::styled-content[@style[.='case'] and @style-type[.='Case-Cal']]]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1][self::styled-content[@style[.='case'] and @style-type[.='Case-Cal']]]/node()"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </styled-content>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="styled-content[@style='case' and @style-type[.='Case-Cal']][preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::styled-content[@style='case' and @style-type[.='Case-Cal']]]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a task for `for-each-group group-adjacent`, in XSLT 3 (available since 2017) it is a bit easier to express than in XSLT 2 as XSLT 3 allows a composite grouping key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[styled-content]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group 
              select="node()" 
              group-adjacent=". is element(styled-content), @style, @style-type" 
              composite="yes">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()[1]">
                      <xsl:copy>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, current-group()/node()"/>
                      </xsl:copy>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzkTd6

If you really need to use XSLT 2 then you need to remove the `composite="yes"`, change the `group-adjacent=". is element(styled-content), @style, @style-type"` to `group-adjacent="string-join((. is element(styled-content), @style, @style-type), '|')"` and the `<xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()[1]">` to `<xsl:when test=". is element(styled-content)">`.

Comment: Thank you so much and will let you know after try this solutions hope fully will work fine

Comment: the <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()[1]"> to <xsl:when test=". is element(styled-content)"> not required to be change for 2.0